# Losing GET data on page reload

Tags: php

I am extracting datas from url for example this is my url:

```
http://localhost/wurkus/reset-password.php?email=zeeshan9@gmail.com&reset_key=$2y$10$vD/o7RgIK8P3S5kLISvmd.puDn5nTlsfMOoxXTKjtWTT1VrG
```

I am storing email and reset_key in two variables

```
if(!empty($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['reset_key'])){
            $email = $_GET['email'];
            $reset = $_GET['reset_key'];
        }
```

The page contains form and when I submit the form $email and $reset are being lost.
is there anyway by which I don't lose these datas even after page reload.

Comment: Put the GET parameters in hidden fields in the form. Or put the information in session variables.

Comment: You seem to be saying conflicting things.  Submitting a form and refreshing the page are very different things.  Actually, I'm not even sure what "refreshing" is supposed to mean -- "reloading" would be a more conventional term for how I'm presently interpreting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a hidden input field. e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
```

If the form data is passed to the same page where the form is present and the form method attribute is "POST" (POST is recommended if the form has sensitive information), then you have to get the values like this--

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['email']))
{ 
  $email=$_POST['email'];
}
?>
```